Github desktop doesn't update after removing repo from github
I mistakenly first pushed a sub-branch to GitHub via GitHub Desktop, and that branch became my default branch. After that, I completely deleted the repo from GitHub, but GitHub Desktop still shows that my repo is on GitHub and the default branch also shows wrong. Can I make the GitHub Desktop and everything go back to before I uploaded my repo to GitHub?
I have important commits and files, and I can't reset commits or create a new repo from scratch.

